# Windows Automation Framework Slowdown

Tags: .net, winforms

I have automated a Windows Forms application using the Windows Automation Framework and noticed that as my tests repeat, the speed of the automation slows down significantly. I've put benchmarks into my automation and noticed that calls to the FindFirst method on the AutomationElement class in particular seem to show steady slowdown. Has anyone here run into this issue, and if so, how did remedy it?

Comment: Memory leak somewhere? Post up the code you are having the automation repeatedly run.

Comment: perhaps garbage collection would help?
maybe nullifying your vars as apart of a cleanup/teardown method after execution
are you closing and reopening the application under test after 10 iterations?